# Install icons from android asset studio

Tags: android

I need to install tab icons from Android asset studio. The downloaded zip contains a res folder with another folders: drawable, drawable-hdpi, etc. I've copied the files from the res/drawable in the downloaded zip, into the res/drawable folder and I've done the same with hdpi, ldpi and mdpi.

Then I used the code:

```
   firstTabSpec.setIndicator("tabname",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_myicon));
```

But the app does not run because there is no icon. My icon does not appear in the list, however, does appear ic_menu_camera and others android icons.

The code works fine with other icons like “ic_menu_camera”.

Could someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I ‘ve not explained properly. What happens is that the app does not run because there is no icon. That’s the problem, my icon does not appear in the list, however, does appear ic_menu_camera and others android icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're importing android.R rather than your project's resources. Can you check your import statements, and remove android.R if it appears?

If that doesn't fix the problem, can you provide more details? The code snippet you provided looks potentially fine, but to help you out, we'd need to see more about your asset layout, filenames, etc.

Comment: Thanks! you were right, I only had to change the import of Android.R for my project import: myproject.R;